# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 411 Error: Length Required (CloudConnect Salesforce sample ETL SOQL validation error)

Tags: soql, custom-object, validation, standard-objects, custom

SOQLvalidation threw validation error in CloudConnect (Clover ETL) Salesforce sample ETL.

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 411 Error: Length Required

Data retrieve target Salesforce organization uses custom domain. I would like to know what caused above error and how to resolve.

Comment: SOAP request was badly formatted.

Comment: The connection target salesforce organization, 'TeamSpirit' is powered by Force.com ERP frontware Salesforce app exchange applicaiton.

Comment: Caused by: com.gooddata.clover.plugin.sfdc.SfdcReaderException: Download poll for project:g6jiyog2ay5ntqhl64h85g0b4dbm19l4 returned error:410 status:Gone response body:{"error":{"errorClass":"com.gooddata.gcf.exception.TaskFailException","trac‌​e":"","message":"Worker task failed: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 411 Error: Length Required","component":"MSF","errorId":"b8840846-d49d-4f57-966b-49e65e47488c","er‌​rorCode":"gdc.gcf.task.fail","parameters":[]}} at com.gooddata.clover.plugin.sfdc.SfdcSoqlReader.executeDownloadTask(SfdcSoqlReade‌​r.java:125) –  Yuya Kobayashi 28 mins ago

Comment: Caused by: com.gooddata.clover.plugin.download.DownloadException: Download poll for project:g6jiyog2ay5ntqhl64h85g0b4dbm19l4 returned error:410 status:Gone response body:{"error":{"errorClass":"com.gooddata.gcf.exception.TaskFailException","trac‌​e":"","message":"Worker task failed: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 411 Error: Length Required","component":"MSF","errorId":"b8840846-d49d-4f57-966b-49e65e47488c","er‌​rorCode":"gdc.gcf.task.fail","parameters":[]}} at com.gooddata.clover.plugin.download.DownloadResultExtractor.executeDownloadAndWa‌​itForFinish(

Comment: Caused by: com.gooddata.commons.http.exception.HttpException: Poll returned status 410: Gone at com.gooddata.service.http.AbstractPollService.generateHttpExceptionFromPollResul‌​t(AbstractPollService.java:198) at com.gooddata.service.http.PollService.handleErrorStatus(PollService.java:79) at com.gooddata.service.http.PollService.handleErrorStatus(PollService.java:21) at com.gooddata.service.http.AbstractPollService.poll(AbstractPollService.java:108) at com.gooddata.service.http.PollService.executeAndPoll(PollService.java:66)